# Array in separate method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, call

I want to write a method with an array which returns a value to main and call the array values in another method. I tried writing it in normal syntax but i cannot get the return to work.

I assume that it isn't possible to return array values?

```
    alienlevel(irritability, level);
    int alienstats[] = new int[level, irritability];
    ...
    ...
    ...
    int alienstats[] = new alienstats[2];
    alienstats[0] = level;
    alienstats[1] = irritability;
    return alienstats[];
```

Comment: Just return `alienstats` (if you declared the method properly, which you haven't shown here). Also, it's recommended not to use the syntax `int alienstats[]` but rather `int[] alienstats` in Java.

Comment: I've a question @RealSkeptic, what's the difference between calling `int[] alienstats` and `int alienstats[]`? I know that the first one creates an `array` of type `int`, but what does the second one do?

Comment: They both declare an array of integers,  but `int[]` is considered better as it shows you immediately that this is an array declaration. The other format is just for compatibility with other languages and is discouraged.

Comment: I've seen the incorrect way written into a lot of codes, and I didn't know if there was any difference. Thank you man @RealSkeptic

Comment: I was taught to create arrays that way @RealSkeptic, thanks for the tip i'll change my format to that. (It actually makes more sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `return alienstats`. The method that does the return would be declared something like:

```
public int[] methodToGetAlienStats()
{
     int[] alienstats = new int[2];
     ...
     return alienstats;
}
```

The calling code would then look like:

```
int[] as = methodToGetAlienStats();
int   alienLevel = as[0];
int   alienIrritabiity = as[1];
```

etc.

Note that a better way to return multiple pieces of data would be to have an `Alien` class, create a `new Alien()` in the method and return it. Then in the caller you could use `Alien.getLevel()` and `Alien.getIrritability()`, instead of relying on the order of the values in the array.

Comment: Ahh thanks for that. but the task needs me to keep the values within an array so instead of calling hunger or irritability multiple times (which i need to do), I'd rather say alienstats[0] to represent hunger.

Comment: @ASehailia You're welcome. Using an array like that instead of a class would be considered poor design, but if you're constrained to do that for outside reasons, then the above will work.